# I am trying to insert account but it is throwing errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, apex

```
public Class Account
{
    public void createAccount(string Name, string label__c) 
    { 
       Account insertAccount = new Account();
       insertAccount.Name = 'ranjith';
       insertAccount.label__c= '123';
       insert insertAccount ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You will need to tell us what errors you're getting, too, and what the results you're expecting are.

Comment: What is `insert insertAccount` should do ? This looks like wrong c# syntax to me. You also should use double quotes instead of single quotes for string :)

Comment: Where do you want to insert into? If you want to insert the data into the database, I suggest that you can use insert into table(name,label_c)values('rajizh','123').

Answer (score 0):

To me your problem looks like it is coming mostly from wrong syntax in your code. Here is your code with fixed syntax :

```
public Class Account
{
    public void createAccount(string Name, string label__c) 
    { 
       Account insertAccount = new Account();
       insertAccount.Name = "ranjith";
       insertAccount.label__c= "123";

       // Commented this line as this looks like a comment and should be replaced by 
       // actual insert logic.

       // insert insertAccount ;
    } 
}
```

In **C#**, strings are defined with double quotes `"` and characters with single quotes `'`.

Also your code doesn't use the parameters you provide to the `CreateAccount` method so here is your code with the method actually using your parameters :

```
public Class Account
{
    public void createAccount(string Name, string label__c) 
    { 
       Account insertAccount = new Account();
       insertAccount.Name = Name;
       insertAccount.label__c= label__c;

       // insert insertAccount ;
    } 
}
```

And the last thing that you should do is read a bit about [naming/coding conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions), how to write variables/methods name. It will help you a lot by making your code more readable by others. So here is your code with these conventions :

```
public Class Account
{
    // Method name should start with a capital letter. Parameters with a lowercase letter.
    // Also try to avoid underscore in variable names
    public void CreateAccount(string name, string labelC)
    { 
       // You can use implicit naming when the type of the variable is obvious like here.
       var insertAccount = new Account();

       // Here I will assume that Name and LabelC are properties, they should start with a uppercase letter.
       insertAccount.Name = name;
       insertAccount.LabelC= labelC;

       // insert insertAccount ;
    } 
}
```

Again, these conventions are not mandatory, you are free to code as you want but it will improve your code a lot and you will have a lot less troubles maintaining it.